# Can Roslyn be used for VB.NET scripting?

Tags: vb.net, roslyn

I'm creating a script editor for my application, and I'd like to have it be able to run both C# and VB.NET scripts using Roslyn.  I got this working with C# by using the `CSharpScript` class in the `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting` assembly/namespace, however there is no equivalent `VisualBasicScript` class that I can find, nor a `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Scripting` assembly.  I've scoured the web and can find nothing useful about running VB.NET scripts, and all the samples on the Roslyn github site are C#-specific.  Am I missing something, or does support for running VB.NET scripts simply not exist the way it does for C# scripts?

Comment: I haven't gone to the extreme of building my own script editor (given that Actipro happen to make one that suits my needs) but I do know (having followed discussions on and off their website)  that although the .net framework (and by extension the languages) were open sourced the actual Roslyn engine / compiler was not so as of this moment their syntax editor doesn't support the newest syntactical nuances of the .net languages.  I'm sorry that this doesn't directly answer you as I don't know for sure but I strongly suspect that the answer at present will turn out to be no.

Comment: I'm using a 3rd party tool (Infragistics xamSyntaxEditor) for the actual text editing / syntax highlighting, and am just building a UI around that to load/save scripts as well as run them and display their results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Visual Basic Scripting is not currently available](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/8248), presumably because [it's not finished](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/6897).

But [its source is is the Roslyn repo](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/tree/master/src/Scripting/VisualBasic), so you could try building it yourself.

When I do that, code like the following works for me:

```
Dim result = VisualBasicScript.RunAsync("Dim result = 1+1").Result

For Each variable In result.Variables
    Console.WriteLine($"{variable.Name}: {variable.Value}")
Next
```

But this code does not work for me (it fails when compiling the script):

```
Console.WriteLine(VisualBasicScript.EvaluateAsync("1+1").Result)
```

I'm not sure whether this is because it's not finished, or whether it's intentional difference from C# scripting.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer and links.  Not exactly what I was hoping for but good to know that it's at least in the works.